# Iterate through particular cells of Excel and export using vb code

Tags: c#, excel, vba, vb.net

I have an Excel sheet as attached below as a drive link. I need a C# or vb code which will read the excel, pick only roll numbers (i.e. 301) and favorite subjects (i.e. Maths) of every student in the excel sheet and export in other Excel (in columns A and B) like:

```
301   Maths
302   English
303   Science
... and so on.
```

Please note the records which I have to pick starts from Row number 200. Rest above this need not to be picked.

I have this code which gets Harry's data only.Need for other students too.

```
Dim appXL As Excel.Application
Dim wbXL As Excel.Workbook
Dim wbsXL As Excel.Workbooks
Dim shXL As Excel.Worksheet
Dim Checker, Checker1 As Integer
appXL = CreateObject("excel.application")
appXL.Visible = True
wbsXL = appXL.Workbooks
wbXL = wbsXL.Open("C:\Users\Pashupati\Desktop\excel.xlsx")
shXL = wbXL.ActiveSheet
Dim rng, rng1 As Excel.Range
rng = CType(shXL.Cells(200, 3), Excel.Range)
rng1 = CType(shXL.Cells(208, 1), Excel.Range)
Checker = rng.Value.ToString()
Checker1 = rng1.Value.ToString()
End Sub()
```

Will appreciate the coordination.

[Click here to view source Excel File](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zlfdhxE_pNsr0gmbMdwInxReELZwtMKJ)

Comment: You can use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel namespace

Comment: So, what's your problem?

Comment: Its getting one student's data only.Need for other students too.Please help with how to put loop here and export the values in another excel

Comment: c#, vb.net or vba? Not all three at once.

Comment: @AJD i have written code in vb.net console application that is mentioned in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub macro1()
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim xrow As Long, q As Long


Set ws1 = Workbooks("StudentData").Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set ws2 = Workbooks("NewWorkbook").Worksheets("Sheet1")

ws2.Cells(1, 2).Value = "Favourite Subjects"
ws2.Cells(1, 1).Value = "Roll no."
xrow = 2

For x = 200 To 300
    If ws1.Cells(x, 1).Value = "Favourite Subjects" Then
        q = x + 1
        ws1.Cells(q, 1).Value = ws2.Cells(xrow, 2).Value
        xrow = xrow + 1
    Else:
    End If
Next x

xrow = 2

For y = 200 To 300
    If ws1.Cells(y, 2).Value = "Roll no." Then
         ws1.Cells(y, 3).Value = ws2.Cells(y, 1).Value
         xrow = xrow + 1
    Else:
    End If
Next y

End Sub
```

Just change the names of the workbooks and worksheets and This should get the job done.  If you get an error then its probably the syntax for using ws1 and ws2 because excel doesn't like transferring data between workbooks.  You can fix this by changing the code to:

```
Sub macro1()
Dim xrow As Long, q As Long

xrow = 2

For x = 200 To 300
    If Cells(x, 1).Value = "Favourite Subjects" Then
        q = x + 1
        Cells(q, 1).Value = Cells(xrow, 6).Value
        xrow = xrow + 1
    Else:
    End If
Next x

xrow = 2

For y = 200 To 300
    If Cells(y, 2).Value = "Roll no." Then
         Cells(y, 3).Value = Cells(y, 5).Value
         xrow = xrow + 1
    Else:
    End If
Next y

End Sub
```

Then copying the D and E columns and pasting them into a new WB.

Comment: PS this code is assuming the data format stay the same throughout the document, and that there is only 1 favorite subject per student.  If that isn't the case let me know and I can update.

Comment: Thank u very much for the help Jane.